# Will General Relativity support "Universe is neither local nor real" in Quantum Gravity Framework?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-entanglement, quantum-gravity

It has been proven conclusively that universe is not locally real as per quantum theory.

But as per GR, universe is locally real with definite properties irrespective if we observe or not.

Scientists are trying to combine these two theories into single framework
Does this mean

1. GR will become theory which support "Universe is neither local nor real"
2. Quantum Theory is locally real (not possible as it has been disproved)

Comment: Define what you mean by "real".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to "local realism": that combines "counterfactual definiteness" (that objects have definite values for properties even when they have not been measured, i.e. the moon still exists even when we're not looking at it) and locality (no faster-than-light effects).

Quantum mechanics does not rule out local realism. Local realism is inconsistent with interpretations involving *wavefunction collapse*. But there are no-collapse interpretations (e.g. the Everett Interpretation) that don't rule it out.

I don't know of any reason why wavefunction collapse should pose any more problems for general relativity than it does already for special relativity. The non-locality is already a problem - if measurement triggers an 'instantaneous' collapse, how does this propagate through spacetime? 'Instantaneous' in which reference frame? And if we change reference frames so 'now' points to a different earlier time, do all the collapses reverse?

I suspect that it will be easier initially to take your option 2 - use a no-collapse unitary-evolution-only interpretation of QM to extend general relativity so that we don't have to deal with faster-than-light effects, and then if we want to restore wavefunction collapse for metaphysical reasons, do it the same way we do currently in QM. We simply assert that all the non-observable components to the superposition magically disappear, along some arbitrary spacelike boundary that we can safely leave unspecified. Since they're not observable, it will make no difference to what the theory predicts.

Answer (score 0):

The term "real" in the context of the discussion of local realism in quantum theory means that measurable quantities have a single value that is revealed by measuring them with measuring devices whose previous evolution was unrelated to the state of the measurement device. Locality roughly means that information is only ever transferred by interactions between systems and any changes between two distant systems are mediated by something that changes at or less than the speed of light. Any theory that reproduces the predictions of quantum theory can be local or realistic but it can't be both.

Quantum theory that hasn't been modified by any sort of collapse mechanism is local because relativistic quantum theories have local equations of motion, but it is not realistic because the evolution of measurable quantities is described by observables that are represented by Hermitian operators not by single numbers:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223

In everyday life we only see one value of a measurable quantity when we measure it. A measurement is an interaction that produces a record that is copied widely. Such interactions prevent quantum interference between different values of observables. As a result, macroscopic systems can be approximately described in terms of quantities with only a single value that obey the laws of classical physics:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189

even though a suitably fine grained description involves many interfering versions of the same system:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

Non-GR classical physics is just the decoherent limit of non-GR quantum theory   and GR may turn out to be the same:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5991

So then quantum gravity could be local but not realistic.

Trying to come up with a realist theory that reproduces all of the predictions of quantum theory has not been successful so far and there are criticisms of the idea it ever will be:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568

Adding more requirements to the theory as we must to reproduce the predictions of general relativity in the relevant circumstances won't make such problems easier:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.12235